# Printing next row ID of MySQL row after page is reloaded

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form where I am dynamically inserting the values from one MySQL table:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="1" size="45">
```

This value="1" is coming from one MySQL table whose `id` parameter is auto-incrementing. So after `id=1` it is `2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9` etc

When I submit the form, it is again reloaded but I want the `id` to be `2` next time. Then the third time, it should be `3`, then `4`, then `5`, etc...

```
$res16 = sql_query("select * from mlf2_entries order by id desc limit 1 ");
    $row = sql_fetch_array($res16);
$textqb = $row['id'];
```

^
I tried this but it always displays value="1"

Comment: Maybe because you need `$row["id"]` rather than `$row["text"]` ?

Comment: sry it was row id only i have written wrongly .but then also it will give single output of first row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is use the offset feature in MySQL's `LIMIT` clause to get the next row. This also accounts for any sequential gaps there may be in the `id` field:

```
SELECT * FROM mlf2_entries ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,1
```

^ This gets the first row in ascending order of the `id` field.

The first number in `LIMIT` clause is the offset. The second number being the number of rows returned (you only want one row, so you can leave that number the same).

To offset to the second row, do `LIMIT 1,1`... to offset to the third row: `LIMIT 2,1`, and so forth and so on.

Comment: @ zane bien this is completely wrong way to do. i have 80000 rows in my table and for every row again and again i will change the code then it will better to use rand() function which is far better than this but i dont want same record again and again

Comment: @ vinayak garg this is completely wrong way to do. i have 80000 rows in my table and for every row again and again i will change the code then it will better to use rand() function which is far better than this but i dont want same record again and again

Comment: @user1515503, well I don't know what you're asking. Do you want the value on the form to increment? Can't you simply keep track of the number of times you submit the form via a PHP variable and just increment the variable +1 each time the form is submitted?

Comment: @zane bien can u please tell how.yes i want in form the value to be increased

Comment: @user1515503 the easiest way is to simply create a hidden form field with the incrementing value: `<input type="hidden" name="incrmt" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['incrmt']) ? $_POST['incrmt']+1 : '1'; ?>" />`... Then for the `title` field, just put this in the value attribute: `value="<?php echo isset($_POST['incrmt']) ? $_POST['incrmt']+1 : '1'; ?>"`